# How to create stage in streamset for redshift using python sdk?

Tags: streamsets

I have been looking for an example or solution for creating a stage in streamset using python sdk. i saw many examples for services such as sql, s3 etc but not specifically for redshift

#Expected
i need to create a pipeline to load data from s3 to redshift using streamsets sdk. I am not sure what are those attributes should set in the configuration for creating stage

There are very few examples available in the streamsets document unlike examples available in the snowflake documentation

I am quite wondering how someone can build streamset pipeline without having proper references on this

Any reference to this ?